# A repo-wide rebase of a commit

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-amend

Consider this line of commits.

```
foo: a => b => c => d
                      \bar: => e => f => g
```

I start out with branch `foo` and occasionally create the new branch `bar` from `foo`. Now, as I am working on commit `h` in branch `bar`, I realize that I made a mistake in commit `c`. So, I run `git rebase` and open up commit `c` for editing. I make my changes, stage them and run `git rebase --continue`.

Now, my `bar` branch is updated. However, the `foo` branch still points to the original flawed version of commit `c`.

Is there a way of running a repo-wide rebase in which all branches that contains pointers to a particular commit are identified and rebased, one at a time?

I know the manual way - rebase foo and insert/cherry-pick the new SHA, but it requires me to know what branches reference the commit. And it requires manual labor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how branches work in git.  They're not whole histories, just pointers to a single commit.  That is, `foo` is really just a synonym for `d`, and `bar` is a synonym for `g`.  Rebasing `bar` doesn't affect `foo` in any way.

If you want to set foo to your new `d` (let's call it `d'`), just do:

```
git checkout foo
git reset --hard d'
```

Here's an example based on yours:

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g
               ^              ^
               |              |
              foo            bar
```

Now, after you do the rebase on `bar`, you have divergent history:

```
          /- c <- d   
         /        ^
a <- b <-         |
         \       foo
          \
           \- c' <- d' <- e' <- f' <- g'
                                      ^
                                      |
                                     bar
```

All you want to do is point `foo` at `d'`, using the `reset` command described above:

```
  a <- b <- c' <- d' <- e' <- f' <- g'
                  ^                 ^
                  |                 |
                 foo               bar
```

This operation orphans `c` and `d` - they'll get garbage collected eventually.

Comment: I don't neccessarily want to do that, perhaps I have added commit `i` to `foo` in the meantime.

If branches are only pointers to certain commits, how come two branches can have a different string of commits? Consider branch 1 `a -> b -> c1 -> d` and branch 2 `a -> b -> c2 -> d`.

In this case, branch1 and branch2 two point to the same commit, `d`, but in branch1 the previous commit is `c1`, which branch2 has `c2` as previous commit because of a rebase.

Comment: If you added `i` to `foo`, you need to rebase as you mention.  Every commit has a reference to its parent commits - the way you have the arrows is backwards.  Let me fix that in my answer, it might make more sense.  It's impossible to have `a <- b <- c1 <- d` and `a <- b <- c2 <- d`... the second case has to have `d2`.  `d` and `d2` might have the same logical contents, but they're different commits with different parents and different hashes.

Comment: the bar commit `d'` is identical to the foo commit `d` - are you telling me they become distinct commits?

Comment: Yes.  They become separate commits.  That's what the rebasing is doing - editing history. You'll notice that the commit hash changes.  `d'` is *not* identical to `d` - it has a different parent.

Comment: I just did a test and you are right. I never noticed this before. Thanks for the explanation. But I guess that also means that even if commit d and d' are identical in changes, they have different hashes and thus git cannot deduce that editing `d'` could imply editing `d` as well.